# How can I change the bulb in this light fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I would like to change the light bulb in the room because the bulb died on me. Trouble is, it is fixed to the ceiling and I cannot take the bulb out. I am attaching two pictures here. On one of the pictures, there is a little knobby looking thing on the top and a slit just below it. I tried pressing on the knob/slit and twisting and turning the whole thing, but nothing happened..it moved a bit but did not come loose. How do I go about this?

[image]

[image]

I also just tried pulling on it (probably not  a good idea), but it looked like it might break :)

Comment: How about spinning just the center glass, not the entire fixture?

Comment: Do you know the manufacturer of the fixture?

Comment: @BMitch: Thanks. The diameter of the steel rim is less than the diameter of the glass, so spinning it merely spins it, does not make it come loose.

Comment: @Tester101: This came when i got the condo...I did  not install it. So I cannot figure out the manufacturer

Comment: Looks like there's a tab just sticking up from the slot in the second picture (hard to tell because it's not quite in focus).  Have you tried seeing if that slides and releases the globe? Or inserting something (wood or plastic, not metal) into the slot to see if that is the release mechanism?  Maybe it moves the tab...

Comment: Is it spring-loaded and just pulls down a little hard, perhaps?

Comment: @Tester101:Hey...I found out...the manufacturer is home depot in canada.

Comment: Are there two metal sections? It seems like the crease in the fixture might be threaded? Maybe insert a flat head screw driver in the slot to hold the top piece and try spinning the lower section to unscrew it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it just pulls down, there are usually little springs that keep it in place. Like the one pictured below

[image]

[Source](http://www.familyhandyman.com/DIY-Projects/Lighting/Interior-Lighting/upgrade-a-recessed-light-fixture/View-All)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answer they can also be kept up there using these spring type flaps and could require some downwards force to remove them.

[image]

Also sometimes you just need to rotate the fixture (holding it by the base not the lights) and turn it right or left with some sligfht jiggle movement to ease it out. It should not turn more than 1/4 of a circle. If it does a full 360 then you need to stop(you will tangle the wires up and its obvious it wont come loose from rotations) I cannot find any picture to demonstrate this sorry.